# azure not displaying vue resources and bootstrap

Tags: azure, vue.js, azure-web-app-service

We deployed our website to azure and only html shows up. It is not loading any of the front end.

[image]

Comment: You have to deploy the contents of the `dist` folder.

Comment: have you `npm run build` to generate the compressed files?